# How can I list the database connections in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

How can I get the list of database connections in Laravel. I'm planning to load the connection names into a select box.

```
'connections' => [
    'sqlsrv_auth' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'SQLEXPRESS'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'auth_db'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'sa'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '1234'),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],
    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'SQLEXPRESS'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'main_db'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'sa'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '1234'),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],
    'sqlsrv_bpb' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', '192.168.1.1'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mirror'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'sa'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '1234'),
        'charest'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ]

],
```

Comment: Yes it is possible use `DB::connection()`

Comment: Check this link:- https://lukevers.com/2015/03/25/on-the-fly-database-connections-with-laravel-5

Comment: got it.. using Config::.. thanks..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it..

```
use Config;

public function test() {
    print_r(Config::get('database'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

secondDb variable now hold connection of 'sqlsrv_bpb' (Name of connection)

```
$secondDb =  DB::connection('sqlsrv_bpb');
```